# Capturing the error message / error handling

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

We use mySQL Workbench ( Maria DB 5.5 )for our maintaining our datawarehouse envmt.I am looking for good error handling options for my stored procedures. Based on my reading, i see that we cannot use the Diagnostics features such as RETURNED_SQLSTATE, MYSQL_ERRNO etc in the lower versions of Maria DB (which is us:().

But each time a query errors out -- we see the error message, how long the duration/fetch took etc.  Is it possible to capture the Action and Message from the workbench system tables ?

I am absolutely new to these things -- Appreciate your help and patience ! Thank you :)
nia

Right now we just put a string "Error" . So if the stored procedure errors out all we know that it errored out. There is not error code or message.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3p4aY.png)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using Declare Handler ?

```
DECLARE handler_type HANDLER
    FOR condition_value [, condition_value] ...
    statement

handler_type:
    CONTINUE
  | EXIT
  | UNDO

condition_value:
    SQLSTATE [VALUE] sqlstate_value
  | condition_name
  | SQLWARNING
  | NOT FOUND
  | SQLEXCEPTION
  | mysql_error_code
```